# ProcessBuilder can't find perl

Tags: java, ioexception, processbuilder

I'm trying to execute a perl script from java with the following code:

```
    ProcessBuilder script =
    new ProcessBuilder("/opt/alert-ssdb.pl");
    Process tmp =  script.start();
```

But when I execute it it returns

```
 java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/opt/alert-ssdb.pl": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:488)
at scripttest.main(scripttest.java:11)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:164)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:81)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:470)
... 1 more
```

about the file

```
ls -l alert-ssdb.pl
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root alert-ssdb.pl
```

I tried running /usr/bin/perl/ with the script as an argument and it also failed with the same exception.

/bin/ls and other simple commands run without a problem though.
Also the first line of the script is #!/usr/bin/perl
and when run on command line it works

what am I missing?

//Update:
The big picture is that I'm trying to call the script via a storm bolt and it fails at that point.
I managed to make it work by defining a python script as a bolt 
using

```
 super(python,myscript.py)
```

(myscript imports the storm library) and from myscript I call the perl script.
I haven't tried yet but I suppose that If I modify the perl script to be a storm bolt it will run nicely.

Comment: What's the first line of `alert-ssdb.pl`?  If the line is something like `#!<some-filename>` and that file doesn't exist, you can still get a "no such file" error depending on how you run it.

Comment: Does the perl script work fine when executed from the shell prompt?

Comment: Did you use `/usr/bin/perl/` or `/usr/bin/perl`? The first one won't work.

Comment: when executed on the command line the script works,
the first line of the file is #!/usr/bin/perl and it's the correct path for perl

Comment: What sort of system are you running this on? Underlying OS I mean? It's not supposed to matter with Java, but it sometimes does especially when you're dealing with stuff like `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: Looking at the Exception, it looks like the file `/opt/alert-ssdb.pl` is not found? I may be wrong but double check the path, also be sure that the script is executable (`chmod +x`).

Comment: I'm running under scientific linux 6
 /optalert-ssdb.pl is executable, anyway,  I fixed it (kind of :P) thanks for the input

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
    new ProcessBuilder("/opt/alert-ssdb.pl");
```

to:

```
    new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/perl", "/opt/alert-ssdb.pl");
```

I've had past experiences where not all my environment variables from the shell exist when using `ProcessBuilder`.

Edited to reflect @dcsohl's comment.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/perl", "/opt/alert-ssdb.pl")`?

Comment: @dcsohl Thanks for catching my mistake. Updated per your comment.

Comment: Thx for the answers, I already tried that
"I tried running /usr/bin/perl/ with the script as an argument and it also failed with the same exception."

Comment: No need to get huffy. You can write "I tried running /usr/bin/perl/ with the script as an argument and it also failed with the same exception," but that doesn't necessarily mean you tried `new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/perl", "/opt/alert-ssdb.pl");` so we're asking.

Comment: Terribly sorry, I wasn't trying to insult anybody :-),
I kind of made it work, I'll update the post with more information